# When I run this code it gives me an unknown option "-menu" error

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I am designing a Gui Application, it makes has 3 root windows. But I am trying to create a drop down menu in the second window but it gives me an error.

```
    class Window2:
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.master = master
    self.master.title("Restaurant Management System")
    self.master.geometry('1350x750+0+0')
    self.frame2 = Frame(self.master)
    self.frame2.configure(background='green')
    self.frame2.pack()

    menu_list = Menu(self.frame2)
    self.frame2.config(menu=menu_list)

    subMenu = Menu(menu_list)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File",menu=subMenu)
    subMenu.add_command(label="New Project...")
    subMenu.add_command(label="New...")
    subMenu.add_separator()
    subMenu.add_command(label="Exit")

    editMenu = Menu(menu_list)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Edit",menu=editMenu)
    editMenu.add_command(label="Copy \t\t Ctrl+C")
    editMenu.add_command(label="Paste \t\t Ctrl+V")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Add menu not to the Frame, but to the window itself:

```
self.master.configure(menu=menu_list)
```

Also, you have a mistake with variable names. Instead of

```
menu.add_cascade(...)
```

use

```
menu_list.add_cascade(...)
```

Comment: it worked thank you Leo Leontev, it seems i was configuring my menu to the frame and not the window itself...thank you very much.